# What is the origin of "the sun is shining, the birds are chirping, and x"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

What is the origin of "the sun is shining, the birds are chirping, and x"?

This sentence construction is common in American media as far as I can tell, with the 'x' being something that is completely unrelated to the idyllic natural setting implied by 'the sun is shining, the birds are chirping.'

I have found lots of examples of 'x' while searching, such as "there's a 60% discount!", "people are complaining", and "the backyard is the best place to be" but no source describing its origins/first use.

Comment: Investigating actual results from [Google 4-grams for  the sun is shining + the birds are chirping](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sun+is+shining%2Cthe+birds+are+chirping&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I can see little evidence that the twinned version was at all common before (or indeed in) modern times.

Comment: I don’t see evidence of this “non sequitur” usage you describe. If you take the phrase to meanly, roughly, that it’s spring, your examples make sense: *It’s spring and that means it’s time for our annual sale. It’s spring and people are complaining (about pollen or noisy birds). It’s spring and the backyard is the best place to be.*

Comment: Yeah, it's safe to say that saecastic usage overall is fairly frequent, though I might be wrong if its best delivered with subject focus maintained. It's not clear if this sarcasm is the point of the question or the lexicality of the phrase what amounts to a Disney movie introduction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for the origin of a commonplace observation "The sun is shining and the birds are singing (chirping) in the trees...” It is like asking what is the origin of "I love my children"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I disagree. Per my interpretation, the OP is asking about how/when 'the sun is shining and the birds are chirping" turned into an ironic self-aware cliche used to preface a non sequitur.

Comment: @Heartspring please show evidence that 1. it is used as an ironic, banal phrase used to trivialise and disdain stories and events. 2. evidence when this usage actually *began*, because I am not convinced by any of the answers posted so far. A 17th century quotation, fables  and a child's account of an idyllic Sunday don't quite make the cut for me. The invite also extends to the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're not really asking for the right thing. Where I live, and in the media that I see, "the sun is shining and the birds are chirping" is not exactly a 'commonplace' observation, (it's pretty much always followed by a third unrelated term) and it's never used disdainfully. I believe Heartspring has answered my question sufficiently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite naturally, people have been associating a shining sun and chirping birds together for a long time, at least since [the late 19th century:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Days_of_grace/HQgCAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20sun%20is%20shining,%20the%20birds%20are%20chirping&pg=PA342&printsec=frontcover)

> "Well, I don't know," she answered with a smile. "I confess that when I was a girl of twelve I did not step with enthusiasm into our dark, chilly school-room on **Sunday afternoons when the sun was shining, the birds chirping and singing in the trees, and the fields teeming with flowers."**

And from [1905](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oswald_Bastable_and_Others/3lw3mNC8z1YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20sun%20is%20shining,%20the%20birds%20are%20chirping,%20and&pg=PA275&printsec=frontcover):

> ﻿The day when everything began to happen to the Princess began just like all her ordinary days. **The sun was shining, the birds were singing,** and the Princess jumped out of bed and ran into the nursery to let the mice out of the traps in the nursery cupboard.

[Here's](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Journals_of_Thomas_James_Cobden_Sand/N4IsAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20sun%20is%20shining,%20the%20birds%20are%20chirping,%20and&pg=PA218&printsec=frontcover) another early example, which could have been written anytime between 1879 and 1922. I think it's the first time you see something slightly un-spring-related added to the phrase, with the creaking carts.

> ﻿*13th July, Monday morning.*
> A sudden feeling of contentment, of peace and happiness, moved me to make an entry here. **The sun is again shining, birds are chirping, and carts are creaking along the high-way.** O happy life! O God, teach me to be good. Teach me to persevere in the quiet ways of work.

The origin of the phrase in its early use is quite obvious: it immediately sets a scene of a happy, romantic springtime. I don't think that this is really something that was 'coined.' The modern use in the media is slightly ironic and non-sequitur, and I assume that this is why it's become so popular. I can't find a first-usage for that, but the above examples do show that it goes pretty far back.

Answer (score 1):

The expression, and others like it are standard examples of the literary device **bathos** See with Wiki entry [bathos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathos)

> ...first used in this sense in Alexander Pope's 1727 essay "Peri Bathous", to describe an amusingly failed attempt at presenting artistic greatness.
>
> Today, bathos refers to rhetorical anticlimax, an abrupt transition from a lofty style or grand topic to a common or vulgar one.

Your

> with the 'x' being something that is completely unrelated to the idyllic natural setting implied by 'the sun is shining, the birds are chirping.'

is the **exact** effect that bathos is intended to produce.

It is a standard form of humour delivered by a standard form of literary device. The Americans are very good at it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the quote

“The sun is shining and the bird are singing what more could you ask for in a day!”

— Heather Mills

been unable to place the context. She was born in 1968 so I'm sure the sentiment may have been worded before then

Comment: It's strange to see how that quote is used everywhere without the punctuation I would assume it to have. That makes me wonder if this quote is just being picked up from some single source on the internet and copied to all websites with quotations. However, do you have an original source for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard the variant with "singing" instead of "chirping." It appears to be quite old. The earliest example I can find is [John Mitchell, *The Female Pilgrim* (1762):](https://books.google.com/books?id=AfG_Cpfhn_cC&pg=PA404&dq=sun+shining+birds+singing&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJlKGo767-AhVtkIkEHRc3AWkQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=sun%20shining%20birds%20singing&f=false)

> In this grove she also met with several other things, which were exceedingly delightful to her, such as the sun shining upon her, the birds singing in the trees, [...]

I suspect that the quote may ultimately have been inspired by [*Paradise Lost.*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/26/26-h/26-h.htm) from the 1674 edition:

> Sweet is the breath of Morn, her rising sweet,
> With charm of earliest birds: pleasant the sun,
> When first on this delightful land he spreads
> His orient beams